# %in% operator for numeric vector returns weird behavior

Tags: r, search, vector, numeric

I have a simple check in place but i lack consistency in the return value. I can not see the issue.

Code example  is a sequence from 0 to 1 in steps of 0.1 and check to see a number is present in this vector

```
    numsequence <- seq(0,1,0.1)
    0.2 %in% numsequence # gives TRUE
    0.3 %in% numsequence # gives FALSE
    0.4 %in% numsequence # gives TRUE 
    0.5 %in% numsequence # gives TRUE
    0.6 %in% numsequence # gives FALSE
```

My own construct which does not work as well

```
    numsequence <- seq(0,1,0.1)
    vectortosearch <- unique(simResults_SURU$ReusePrevBefore)
    vectortosearch
    # [1] 0.0 0.1 0.2 0.3 0.4 0.5 0.6 0.7 0.8 0.9 1.0
    str(vectortosearch)
    # num [1:11] 0 0.1 0.2 0.3 0.4 0.5 0.6 0.7 0.8 0.9 ...
    for(v in vectortosearch){
        print(v)
        if (v %in% numsequence ){
            print(v)
        }
    }
```

gives the following output
0
0
0.1
0.1
0.2
0.2
0.3
0.4
0.4
0.5
0.5
0.6
0.7
0.8
0.8
0.9
0.9
1
1

This construct works for all numbers

```
    for(number in numsequence){print(number);print(number %in% numsequence)}
```

Any one has an idea why it does not work? Why 0.3 and 0.6 and 0.7 are left out the loop?

Expecting to see all numbers from the sequence vector to be displayed following the %in% operator

Comment: Could you provide a sample of simResults?

Comment: `floor(.3) %in% ...` should work.